# is it possible to add a class to header found in page.tpl based on a node id?

Tags: theming

first off, i’m using Adaptive Theme so maybe this won’t make sense using a different theme. but here i want to add a class to

```
<header id=“main-content-header” class="someclasses">
```

which is found in page.tpl but based on node id. this would have to be done in mysubtheme_preprocess_page(). i have part of the code working.

```
 $variables['content_header_attributes_array']['class'][] = 'about'
```

but don’t know how to ascertain the node id that is contained on the page. is it possible? my pseudo code would read something like

```
if (nodeId == 1){
 $variables['content_header_attributes_array']['class'][] = 'about'
}
```

by the way, i find myself needing to do this constantly so i can style these headers differently, at least for this project i do. maybe there’s a better way to accomplish,..?

i can use conditional stylesheets but then there’s the issue of adaptive design and you’d have to put media query’s in these conditional stylesheets. don’t know if that’s such a good idea or not.

Comment: @samuelsov is right. But to get node id you can do this: $node = menu_get_object(); if ($node) { // use $node->nid}

Answer (score 5):

You probably already have a specific class for the page on the `<body>` tag.

For example :

```
<body class="html not-front not-logged-in page-node page-node- page-node-5 node-type-page">
```

Then a css should work for you :

```
body.page-node-5 #main-content-header { ... }
```

or

```
body.node-type-page #main-content-header { ... }
```

Comment: yes thanks, good point but i really want to get under the hood w/ the PHP and process & preprocess functions

Comment: but that is a very good answer, thank you